# Can a View be reached in MVC without that view being returned or redirected to?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Is there any way that an MVC view could be hit without that view being explicitly returned. In other words, is there some delegated redirect or back-end default page load in ASP.NET-MVC that could throw to a view without that view's name showing up anywhere in the source code? Because if so, I would like to be able to pinpoint all places in my code that could cause a given view to be loaded, even without explicitly returning that view.

**Edit for clarity:**

I just want to know how/if any View could get loaded without that view being explicitly returned or redirected to from an ActionResult so that I can identify the block of code that is causing the page to get hit.

Here is my RouteConfig.cs

```
public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Default", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
        private static string EnsureTrailingSlash(string value)
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                value = string.Empty;
            }

            if (!value.EndsWith("/", StringComparison.Ordinal))
            {
                return value + "/";
            }

            return value;
        }
    }
```

Here are some potentially relevant sections from my Web.config

```
<configuration>
......
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>

  <system.web>
    <compilation>
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Are you using attribute routing, and if so, does that route have a name? An attribute-routed action can have a name that is different than the action name and the route itself, yet you can still redirect to that action using the route name.

Comment: You are going to need to post some code. Your controller `Index` `Action`, or routing table and home page, if home view is not generated by `Index`. Your question structure makes it difficult to answer. Do you want help with your problem? Or do you want the answer to a 1 paragraph question that doesn't really make sense. Are you just trying to render a custom error page? That you would do in `Web.config` file

Comment: Post edited for clarity (hopefully).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be from outside the code. Check if where you are hosting your web app if there is any special rules set in place that are automatically showing your errror.cshtml page.

Also, check your web.config if there are special rules in there:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" defaultResponseMode="ExecuteURL">
            try looking in here for something like this
        </httpErrors>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Without seeing anymore of your code or what not it is tough to say exactly. But this might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks. I am reticent to start posting code because I really don't know what code is involved and want to avoid posting a huge code-block. I've added some code to the original post.